# setting an argument in the Makefile

Tags: makefile, macros, rpmbuild, rhel6

All the other variables used are defined

```
OPT='_topdir ${TOPDIR}'

rpmbuild --buildroot ${TOPDIR}/BUILDROOT/${RPM_NAME}-${VER}-${RELEASE}.${ARCH} --define=$(OPT) -vv -ba ${RPM_NAME}.spec
```

ERROR :

```
make: *** [depend-recursive] Error 1
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.nsEjuv (%build)


RPM build errors:
    Macro % has illegal name (%define)
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.nsEjuv (%build)
```

Comment: Could you show us the makefile and tell us how you invoked it? A [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be even better.

Comment: I don't believe that command line is the problem. What does your rpmmacros file look like? What about the specfile itself?

Comment: command : make - that is how I am invoking the Makefile. Basically I am trying to build my own rpm package for the Apache htppd 2.4.10 . rpmmacros file is fine, verified it. Sorry, can't share the code here.